# Compound Process and its compensator

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I have always implicitly thought that for a counting process $N_t$, defining the compound process $$\sum_{i=1}^{N_t} X_i,$$ where $X_i$ are i.i.d, was pretty much equivalent to constructing a stochastic integral $$\int_0^t X_s\,dN_s=\sum_{\tau_i<t}X_{\tau_i},$$ if $\tau_i$ are the jump times of $N_t$, for "some" process $X_t.$

Then, I realised that if $N_t$ is a simple Poisson process, then the compensator of the first one is $\lambda t \mathbb E[X_1]$, while for the second it is $\lambda \int_0^t X_s\,ds$. So I guess the two constructions must be different.
Hence my question, is there a way to find the compensator of the compound process, for a general point process $N_t$ with intensity $\lambda_t$?

Comment: This is a good reference on the compensators of counting processes https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2011/12/27/compensators-of-counting-processes/
(but unfortunately not for *compound* counting processes.)

Comment: @AmercianCaller : I think that the way use use X in your first representation and in your second one are not fully coherent with one another, could you elaborate or clarify the formal link between $X_i, X_s$  and X_{\tau_i}$. Best regards.